# Do I have to return to daggers I found for the quest Shine and Shadow?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm on a quest to find some artifacts for a guy named Avicenn. He wanted me to find Shine and Shadow. Well, I found them and not only are they artifacts but they are a pair of *freakin' awesome* daggers that are incredibly better then what I'm using. I don't want to just ignore the guy (mostly because I hate having unfinished quests in my log) but I really don't want to give them up.

When I return to Avicenn, is there an option for keeping them? Fight him? Pay him off?

Comment: Please limit platform tags to questions which are platform specific. :)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Sorry :) Will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you complete the quest he **may** take the daggers depending on your persuasion skill.  If your persuasion is high you may be able to keep them, the chance is 47% if your persuasion is 0 though.

Comment: Quicksave shenanigans seem like the way to go, then!

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's the plan!